How do I use the EmergencyNumber class?
I'm extremely new to android/kotlin, and I'm having trouble with some basics. I have an app that should call the emergency number when a button is clicked, and I'm having trouble getting the emergency number programmatically. I've found the EmergencyNumber class, but I'm not sure how to make an object so I can call getNumber(). I'm doing this within a fragment.
I tried val num: EmergencyNumber = EmergencyNumber(), which gives the "Cannot access '': it is package-private in 'EmergencyNumber'" error.

"I have an app that should call the emergency number when a button is clicked" -- ordinary apps are not allowed to call the emergency number. That requires the CALL_PRIVILEGED permission, which ordinary apps cannot hold.

In addition to what's stated above, that class doesn't have a public constructor.  You can't create an instance, which is what you're trying to do.  You can get passed an instance to it, but cannot construct one.
